# How to display dropdown menu in macOS swiftUI

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

i have a button if pressed, will show items in a dropdown menu. But i'm not sure how to display a menu showing the itmes after pressing the button. This is for a macOS app.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, world!")
            .padding()

        Button {
         
        }

        label: {
            Image(systemName: "bookmark.circle")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width:24.0, height: 24.0)
         }
        .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
        
      
    //List items that i want to display in the dropdown menu
    
    ForEach((1...5), id: \.self) {
            Text("\($0)")
            Divider()
        }         
   }       
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Menu`:

```
Menu {
    ForEach((1...5), id: \.self) {
        Text("\($0)")
        Divider()
    }
} label: {
    Image(systemName: "bookmark.circle")
        .resizable()
        .frame(width:24.0, height: 24.0)
}
```

You can also use `ContextMenu` if you want a *right-click* menu

Comment: Thank you this works, is there a way to only show the "bookmark.circle" label? because it's also showing a blue drop down button next to the label.

Comment: You can play with `menuStyle` but I'm not sure if there is a prebuilt style matching your requirements (for mac). You may want to create your own menu for full customization access.